# Numerical gradient in spherical coordinates

Tags: numerical-analysis

Assume that we have a function $u$ defined in a ball in a discrete way: we know only the values of $u$ in the nodes $(i,j,k)$ of spherical grid, where $i$ is a radius coordinate, $j$ is a coordinate for angle $\varphi$, $k$ is a coordinate for angle $\psi$.

Consider a vector-function 
$$\nabla u_{i,j,k}=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}_{i,j,k},\frac{1}{r_i\sin\psi_k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}_{i,j,k},\frac{1}{r_i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}_{i,j,k}\right)-$$
gradient of $u$.

I need to know the values of $\nabla u_{i,j,k}$ on z-axis in cartesian coordinates, which corresponds to $\psi=0$ -- axis in spherical coordinates, but we can not use the formula above, because in case $\psi=0$ the second term turns to infinity.

Actually, we can find the values of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ with a help of the formula of numerical derivative, but we have a problem with finding $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, because the grid is not rectangular. Could you help me with this stuff and advise me what to do?

Comment: Could you not calculate the numerical derivative in the $(r,\varphi,\psi)$ coordinate system? This should give you a vector which you can then project onto the $x$- $y$- and $z$-axes to give you the $x$- $y$- and $z$-components of the gradient

Comment: No, we can not calculate numerical derivative, because for $\psi=0$ $\varphi$-angle is not defined and we have singularity in formula.

Comment: There is likely a solution using quaternions, but its kinda tricky to figure out what exactly that looks like wrt. your nomencalture.  The effect you are trying to fight is commonly referred to as "[gimbal-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)"

Comment: I found one variant to deal with this stuff correctly : here we can use least square method for gradient reconstruction, but I did not find exact explanation, how to use it

Comment: Perhaps it's the case - for moderately well behaved $u$$ - that $\lim_{\psi\to 0} \frac{1}{\sin \psi} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi}=0$. But I don't think the middle component of your vector has meaning, so if you're plugging this into a differential equation in polar coordinates the differential equation might also give no weight to the middle coordinate.

Comment: I thought about this variant, but the middle coordinate has meaning for equations with non-identity matrix $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to avoid this situation, but before use one must check if this way is suitable due to computation error:

1) Green-Gauss cell method: here the definition of gradient is used:

$$\nabla u_i \approx\frac{1}{V_{i}} \int\limits_{\partial V_i}u d\overline{S}\approx \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{u_{f_k} S_k \overline{n}_k} , $$ where $k$ - numbers of neighbours of cell $V_{i}$

2) Least squares method: the error

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{d_{ik}}E_{i,k}^{2}}, E_{i,k}=\nabla u_i \cdot\Delta r_{i,k}+u_i-u_k $$ must be minimized, hence we get the components of $\nabla u_i$

3) Interpolation method. The value of gradient is interpolated from the values of gradient vector-function.